# Pin layout convention for DC transmitted over a GX16 aviation plug

Tags: aviation-electronics

Is there a convention or a standard or a recommendation on when DC is transmitted over a GX16 aviation plug 2-pin, where is plus or where is minus? I saw linear power supplies which converted AC to DC and had DC output via a GX16 2-pin, but there were differences in the assignment of the positive and negative terminals. I've noticed that some manufacturers assign the positive terminal to pin 2, as on the attached picture, while others assign it to pin 1. This inconsistency can lead to confusion and potential damage to equipment if the polarity is reversed. Is there a universally accepted standard for the assignment of positive and negative terminals in a GX16 2-pin aviation plug? If not, what precautions should be taken when using these plugs to ensure correct polarity?

[image: GX16 2-pin layout sample]

Comment: Your questions is OK and on-topic here, but I suspect that you would get a better answer asking at https://aviation.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

These are generic connectors for any generic purpose and thus any manufacturer can define the pins in any way. And they already did.

So even if a standard or preferred way did exist, it does not change the fact you already found, there already are devices with both polarities.

As a precaution, you could build your device to have reverse polarity protection between receptacle and any other electronics so it can handle reverse polarity.

You could also build your device to handle both polarities or even AC so the polarity of plug supplying the receptaclr in your device does not matter.

However, such a protection circuit cannot be into the power supply or cable plug side.